# Prepositions with specific times

Tags: sentence-construction

I have formulated several sentences in daily usage as below (describing time), but I am not sure which is or are correct.

> **A:** Can I take this coach (at or on) any time of tomorrow?
>   **B:** Can I take it anytime tomorrow?
>
> **C:** We will arrive at the pier tomorrow afternoon.
>   **D:** We will arrive at the pier on the afternoon of tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

**For A**: Use ***at*** *any time* (not ***on*** *any time*), and don't use *of* before *tomorrow*:

> Can I take this coach at any time tomorrow?

**For B**: The sentence is fine:

> Can I take this coach anytime tomorrow?

**For C**: The sentence sounds like fluent, idiomatic English.

**For D**: Again, don't use *of* before *tomorrow*; also, it's generally ***in** the afternoon*, not ***on** the afternoon*:

> We will arrive at the pier in the afternoon tomorrow.

Although we could also word that as:

> We will arrive at the pier tomorrow afternoon.

and we'd use the preposition *on* if we were using the name of a specific day:

> We will arrive at the pier on Tuesday afternoon.
>   We will arrive at the pier in the afternoon on Tuesday.

(As a footnote, I wouldn't argue that "on the afternoon of tomorrow" is ungrammatical, it's just clunky and I'd recommend avoiding it.)

Comment: Interestingly, we do say say things like *on the morning after the accident*, *on the evening of the twenty-first*, or *on the night when he proposed*, but I can't think of a construction where *on the afternoon* sounds natural.